# Android RunTime Permissions

Tags: android, android-fragments, fatal-error, android-permissions, runtime-permissions

I am trying to add runtime permissions to make an app compatible for API 23+. I went through the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) but when I just include the following line

`private final int hasWriteFilePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);`,

my app crashes and I get the following error:

```
07-10 20:54:15.571 31479-31479/com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.examples E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                             Process: com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.examples, PID: 31479
                                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.examples/com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.examples.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3254)
                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350)
                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795)
                                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
                                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
                                                                                                 at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:337)
                                                                                                 at android.widget.AbsSpinner.setAdapter(AbsSpinner.java:115)
                                                                                                 at android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(Spinner.java:554)
                                                                                                 at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.examples.MainActivity$FragmentTabSTT.addItemsOnSpinnerModels(MainActivity.java:566)
                                                                                                 at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.examples.MainActivity$FragmentTabSTT.onCreateView(MainActivity.java:190)
                                                                                                 at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2281)
                                                                                                 at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:983)
                                                                                                 at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1163)
                                                                                                 at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793)
                                                                                                 at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1552)
                                                                                                 at android.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:325)
                                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6914)
                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3217)
                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350) 
                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222) 
                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795) 
                                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229) 
                                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

My code is as follows:

```
public static class FragmentTabSTT extends Fragment implements ISpeechToTextDelegate {
    .
    .
    .
@Override
     public void onAttach(Context context) {
         super.onAttach(context);

         Activity a;

         if (context instanceof Activity){
             a = (Activity) context;
         }

     }



     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     .
     .
     .
     }
     .
     .
     .
        // One method that requires permission
public ArrayList<String> GetFiles(String DirectoryPath) {

         int hasReadFilesPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

         if (hasReadFilesPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
             if (!shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                 showMessageOKCancel("You must give permission to read from storage.",
                         new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                             @Override
                             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                 requestPermissions(new String[] {permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                         REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
                             }
                         });
                 return null;
             }

             requestPermissions(new String[] {permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                     REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
             return null;
         }
         ArrayList<String> MyFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
         File f = new File(DirectoryPath);

         f.mkdirs();
         File[] files = f.listFiles();
         if (files.length == 0)
             return null;
         else {
             for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++)
                 MyFiles.add(files[i].getName());
         }

         return MyFiles;
     }
}
```

How should I check for permission within the fragment? What is causing this error? How do I solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: You can check a class that I've created and use it in Fragments https://github.com/mptrista/PermissionHelper
It is very simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getActivity()` returns `null` when a Fragment is first created (i.e., before `onAttach()` is called).

You should check for permissions directly before you need them, rather than keeping them in a final class variable.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but could you please elaborate? The implementation of the method that requires the permission is within the fragment. How do I check for permissions in this case?

Comment: Okay, so put the call to `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission` directly before that line.

Comment: Before 'which' line should I put the call to `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission`?

Slightly updated the code. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Yep! That looks right to me and seems to match the [Runtime permissions video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C8lUdPVSzDk)

Comment: Yes, but the app still crashes when I call the method in onCreateView with the same error.

Comment: Can you update your error message with the new stack trace?

Comment: Updated the error message. The getFile method still returns null.

Comment: That's a totally different error message that has nothing to do with permissions - looks like your code is past that part.

Comment: That is weird because the getFile method worked fine on Android API less than 23 but returns null on API 23.

Comment: I have successfully debugged it. Your answer solved my original problem with the permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Don't call it in a static variable:

```
@Override
onViewCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String[] permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS};
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), permissions, PERMISSIONS_CODE);
}
```

Add a listener for permissions:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    // do stuff
}
```

And you'll need to inherit from AppCompatFragment.